# How can I set the same key to toggle the folding of the current block in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2019, key-bindings, folding

I need to set on one single key (F1 specifically) both the collapse and the expand of the current block, in VS Pro 2019.

I thought I did it in the past, but I seem not to find it again anymore.

Simply binding both `Edit.CollapseCurrentRegion` and `Edit.ExpandCurrentRegion` doesn't work: one overwrites the other.

Ideally there should be a `Edit.ToggleCurrentRegion` but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion
```

I think this should toggle expansion and collapsing of current region. By default it's Ctrl + M + M

Check out more shortcuts here if needed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019